# How to increment i by 3 within for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of random X's and Y's eg[XXYXYYX]

I want to see an X, increment count, then skip the next two numbers.

For example [XXXY] = 1 and [XXXYX] = 2

```
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        if arr[i] == 'X':
            count+=1
            i+=2
        
    return count
```

My solution is not skipping the next two values directly after an X.

Example test:   'XYXXXXXYX.'
WRONG ANSWER (got 7 expected 3)

Example test:   'XXYXXXY’
WRONG ANSWER (got 5 expected 2)

Example test:   'XXXX'
WRONG ANSWER (got 4 expected 2)

Comment: `[XXYXYYX]` does not look like a list, please show your real data in real Python syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'i' variable is being changed by the for loop so if you add 2 to it there is no change. I mean the value of 'i' is changed, but only in this time. Right after that, it is set again and has a new value (set by the for loop).

There is my solution.

```
s = 'XYXXXXXYX'

count = 0
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    if s[i] == 'X':
        count += 1
        i += 3
    else:
        i += 1
print(count) # 3


#With the for loop
count = 0
skipped = 0
is_skipping = False
for i, letter in enumerate(s):
    if not is_skipping:
        if letter == 'X':
            count += 1
            is_skipping = True
    else:
        skipped += 1
        if skipped > 2:
            is_skipping = False
            skipped = 0
print(count) # 3
```

Comment: This works, however, while loops are slower so I would've preferred a for loop solution. Nonetheless good job thank you

Comment: Yeah, while loops are slower but for me, it is not a task for the for loop. I created the solution with the for loop, so you can see, but it is a bit messy.

Comment: You could simplify it with a single variable `skip` telling you how many to skip. But perhaps still simpler to [*actually* skip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68945886/16759116).

Answer (score 1):

Your `i += 2` has no useful effect, because the `for` loop will set `i` to the next value from the range anyway.

You could make it work by turning the range into an iterator yourself so you have access to it, and throwing away the next two indexes after an `'X'`:

```
arr = 'XYXXXXXYX'

count = 0
indexes = iter(range(len(arr)))
for i in indexes:
    if arr[i] == 'X':
        count += 1
        next(indexes, None)
        next(indexes, None)
print(count)
```

Though a non-index version is simpler and clearer:

```
arr = 'XYXXXXXYX'

count = 0
letters = iter(arr)
for letter in letters:
    if letter == 'X':
        count += 1
        next(letters, None)
        next(letters, None)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use simple i+3

```
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        if arr[i] == 'X':
            count+=1
            i = i+3
        
    return count
```

Comment: Same answers. Still counting every X

Answer (score 0):

You can add a skip in the thrid argument in range function

So you would use

```
for i in range(0, len(arr), 2)
```

Comment: But I only want to skip if an X is seen. Won't this skip every 3 regardless so if it is like [YYYYXY] no x would be seen?

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution (maybe the first time I used [`subn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn)).

```
import re

s = 'XYXXXXXYX'

count = re.subn('X.{,2}', '', s)[1]

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `skip` variable that you decrement on iterations that you want to skip over:

```
def f(arr):
    count = 0
    skip  = 0
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        if skip: skip -= 1; continue
        if arr[i] == 'X':
            count+=1
            skip = 2
    return count
```

output:

```
testData = ["XXXY","XXXYX","XYXXXXXYX","XXYXXXY","XXXX"]
for arr in testData:
    print(arr,f(arr))

XXXY 1
XXXYX 2
XYXXXXXYX 3
XXYXXXY 2
XXXX 2
```